# how to generate facebook __dyn and composer_session_id params

Tags: facebook

i'm trying create facebook app and i stuck with this promlem: i need to understand how facebook generates its __dyn and composer_session_id params (you can see them when you post message on your wall). i've just saved all fb js sources but... damn, its realy so hard to understand how they do it.

so if you consider this question as stupid or impudent from my side - sorry... however i really need to understand those params...

any help appriciated!

Comment: nope. recomend to use fb api...

Comment: Is it possible to run the JS and get the generated value?

Answer (score 3):

Try it.

Facebook will not say anything i guess

```
__dyn = ""; // 100%
composer_session_id = ""; // ??
```

Answer (score 1):

I just sent it with empty value.

```
__dyn = ""
```

Hope it will help